# How to detect a message has inline button telegram bot

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I created a group controller bot in telegram.
Now i have a problem: Can i detect messages that contains inline button?

Standard Telegram API doesn't have a method for detecting these messages.

Whats the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messages which are triggered by an inline keyboard will have the key `callback_query`.

This is the structure you will receive.

```
{
  "update_id": 123456789,
  "callback_query": {
    "id": "123456789123456789",
    "from": { ... },
    "message": {
      "message_id": 123456789,
      "from": { ... },
      "chat": { ... },
      "date": 123456789,
      "text": "Message text"
    },
    "chat_instance": "123456789123456789",
    "data": "your_callback_data"
  }
}
```

[Telegram Bot API CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery)

Comment: My bot must delete these messages that sent to group. these messages not for my bot.

Comment: In your `callback_query` you also see the `message` with its `id`. You can use that for [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext) or [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage)